# How can I paste multiple Bitmaps in outlook without losing formatting using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, bitmap, formatting

I'm having two issues when pasting a couple of excel tables as bitmaps into an outlook email. One, I can't copy and paste multiple tables because each paste replaces the last one. Is there a way to paste on after the other in the email? The other issue I'm having is that the bitmap is losing a lot of the table formatting. Is there anyway to keep the formatting? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Dim mailrng As Range, rng As Range
Set mailrng = Sheets("Email").Range("B2")
     
'Copy range of interest
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("Email").Range("E3:P72")

Dim g As Range
Set g = Sheets("Email").Range("W3:AD7")

Dim t As Range
Set t = Sheets("Email").Range("S12:AD17")

r.Copy

'Open a new mail item
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Get its Word editor
outMail.Display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

wordDoc.Range.PasteSpecial (4)

g.Copy

wordDoc.Range.PasteSpecial (4)

t.Copy

wordDoc.Range.PasteSpecial (4)

outMail.To = mailrng
outMail.Subject = Sheets("Email").Range("B1")
outMail.Display
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Range.PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) method pastes a `Range` object that has been copied into the specified range. The first parameter specifies the part of the range to be pasted, such as `xlPasteAll` or `xlPasteValues`.

You need to specify one of the [XlPasteType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype) values that specifies the part of the range to be pasted. For example, you can use `xlPasteAll` or `xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` if you want to preserve the original formatting.